# Let a, b be constant, the correlation between X&Y is the same as the correlation between aX and bY. Why is it so intuitively?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, covariance

I understand how to derive the conclusion mathematically. However, if a is positive and b is negative, the new correlation between aX and bY intuitively will be the opposite of the correlation between X and Y. Just windering where I am wrong in the reasoning.

Comment: True if $a, b > 0.$

Comment: True *if and only if* $ab \gt 0$ or the original correlation is zero.  When you start with the correct mathematical definition of correlation, this result is tautological and needs no proving.  (One such definition is that the correlation is the expected product of the standardized variables: scaling either does nothing to the standardized version of a variable or negates it.) So, please tell us what definition of correlation you are beginning with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is fine. It is the claim of equal correlation that is faulty.

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(2022)
N <- 10
a <- 2
b <- -3
X <- MASS::mvrnorm(N, c(0, 0), matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), 2, 2))
x <- X[, 1]
y <- X[, 2]
cor(x, y)
cor(a*x, b*y)
```

I get equal magnitudes of correlation but opposite signs, disproving the claim.

Maybe an easier example (that skips the `MASS` call) is to simulate independent $x$ and $y$, calculate $cor(x,y)$, and compare to $cor(x, -y)$.

```
set.seed(2022)
N <- 10
x <- rnorm(N)
y <- rnorm(N)
cor(x, y)
cor(x, -y)
```

Comment: just to explain this a little more $cor(x,y) = \frac{cov(x,y)}{\sqrt{var(x)var(y)}}$. Similarly, $cor(ax, by) = \frac{ab cov(x,y)}{\sqrt{a^2var(x)b^2 var(y)}}$. So, when you pull the $a^2b^2$ out of the square root in the denominator, you get the $|ab|$ even though $a$ and $b$ might be opposite sign. So, the whole thing in that case would become negative.